C++ Builder CE 11 Version 28.0.48361.3236 / How can I change the path of __astcache / OneDrive don't like it
My Windows 10 (latest version) is configured to store my files in the cloud.
The problem is that OneDrive sometimes want to change the name of a cache file which is not
Windows naming convention, or better said OD naming convention.
*C:\Users<NAME>\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects__astcache*
Where can I change the path in settings or project options?
So that I can store the cache files on my local HD.
Thank you.
I deleted the files which OD couldn't upload. No solution for me.
I tried the already posted solution here in StackOverflow text
But OD settings let me not enter the @


Try c++ compiler output directory.
